# Error on creating relative path in Jupyter Notebook using read_csv

Tags: python, directory, jupyter-notebook, relative-path

I am a beginner with Jupyter Notebook but here's what I am having trouble with:

I have created a  Python3 file using Jupyter Notebook and have imported my csv file using read_csv.

Then, I created a new folder (named *Park* )- that would include my python file, and the csv file needed (named *MyFile.csv*). The purpose is to be able to run the python file from any computer- not just my own- using this relative path.

So, I do:

```
  import pandas as pd
  data=pd.read_csv('Park/MyFile.csv')
  data.head()
```

And I get this error:

```
No such file or directory: 'Park/MyFile.csv'.
```

On the contrary, when I simply run this:

```
   import pandas as pd
   data=pd.read_csv('MyFile.csv')
   data.head()
```

It runs fine. But will this work (only including the file's name) when I try to run the Python file from other computers?

All I am trying to do is to be able to send out the folder (as zipped maybe?) and have it run smoothly in any computer using a relative path for the csv files.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: there are many questions which show how to create path to script folder - `BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` and later use it to create absolute path for file `os.path.join(BASE, 'Park', 'MyFile.csv')`. And this resolve problem with running code on different computers. But I don't know if it will work with Jupyter because it may not have `__file__`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem comes from the relative path of your system. If you want to run another file under the same directory, you could use "./Myfile.csv".

The "./" stands for father directory of this file - that is the current directory, so it will search file under current directory.

If you input "Park/Myfile.csv", the interpreter will search for "Park" file under current "Park" directory and ends up none existing.